Why can't I connect to Samba server from a Mac?
My main computer (Mac) won't let me connect to my Samba share on my Debian home server. I have followed this YouTube video.
My testparm output:
# Global parameters
[global]
    map to guest = Bad User
    name resolve order = bcast host
    security = USER
    server string = MALAITASMB
    idmap config * : backend = tdb
    include = /etc/samba/shares.conf


[myuser_public]
    create mask = 0664
    directory mask = 0775
    force create mode = 0664
    force directory mode = 0775
    force group = smbgroup
    force user = smbuser
    guest ok = Yes
    path = /share/public
    read only = No

My Mac returns the following whenever I try to connect (as guest):

Interestingly, when I try to connect from inside the server itself, it asks me for the password for [WORKGROUP\user1]. User1 was deleted since I followed the tutorial linked. It no longer exists.
Also, I have set up my server to only allow login over ssh by specifying a port with the -p flag and identifying with a file containing the ssh key (using -i). I am not sure whether this is relevant but I thought I would mention it.

the mac may not know the server by the hostname - could you try using the IP first?

@JourneymanGeek yeah that's what ive been doing smb://{server ip address}/. With my old configuration I would do smb: //{server ip address}/user1_share but as I said, I deleted user1 (my old config wouldn't work either), followed the tutorial I linked, and now I just do smb://{server ip address}/

https://serverfault.com/questions/211128/can-samba-security-user-be-used-for-guest-share-without-windows-login-prompt config looks valid. What's in /etc/samba/shares.conf ?

@JourneymanGeek its a separate file for the shares. It holds the myuser_public share shown in the testparm output.

IIRC samba has its own user system - does smbuser exist? another thing that comes to mind is if avahi is installed - thats zeroconf/rendevous for linux
